# How to return columns with the same name as original table when creating function?

Tags: postgresql

So I have this function:

```
create function report (varchar)
returns table (
        id bigint,
        src_data_system_id int8
)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    return query
        select id, src_data_system_id from process_log_objects plo 
        where src_data_system_name = 'somecondition'||$1;
end $$
```

If in `returns` block I am using the same column names as in select query in a function body, then when I do `select * from report('dict_day');` I am getting an error

```
 ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous
  Detail: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
```

How can I return original column names from this query?

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to qualify the columns with the table name:

```
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT plo.id, plo.src_data_system_id FROM process_log_objects plo
    ...
```

To avoid that kind of problem, it is good style to use different parameter names for the function.

Comment: thank you so much for such quick response! The problem is if I use different parameter names in function I get the different name of the columns when I use function=\